# Swift index out of range when refreshing

Tags: swift, firebase, indexing, tableview, refresh

so ive been tring to solve this on my own for a few hours now. When ever i pull to refresh its crashes saying index out of range. Some people say its because of removing the arrays data before getting it and all that but only confused me further

here is my code

```
    @objc fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser() {

    houses.removeAll()
    myJobs.removeAll()

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
            guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            var post = Post(dictonary: dictionary)
            post.id = key

            Database.database().reference().child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if post.pickedUserId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    self.myJobs.append(post)
                } else if post.hasPicked == true && post.pickedUserId != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid  {
                    print("taken out")
                } else {
                    self.houses.append(post)
                }
                self.houses.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }, withCancel: { (err) in
                print("Failed to fetch like info for post:", err)
            })
        })

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch posts:", err)
    }
}
```

A solution to this error will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you should reload your tableView at once, that means after your data is prepared instead of reload it every single step. (outside forEach loop)

Comment: From my experience these type of errors usually occur when using multi-threaded code on reference types.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are refreshing your tableview because you want to retrieve new data from your database. I say that because you are listening for values from your database once. 

change     `ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in`
to     `ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in`